# How can I set React Native Fontsize as pt?

Tags: react-native

What is React Native FontSize Unit? px or pt?
I want to set fontSize with pt.
How can I do this?

I know that 1em = 12 pt = 16 px.
But I have to set fontsize as 13pt.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

The main unit has been dubbed `dp` (density-independent pixels). For font's it's called `sp` (scale-independent pixels)

From the docs:

> All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels.

This includes font sizes. This is mainly because different phones have different DPIs and units like px will not scale gracefully based on the DPI of every phone.

Sources:

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width.html
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension
- https://material.io/design/layout/understanding-layout.html

Comment: So it means, I cannot set fontsize as pt directly. I have to change sp fontsize to pt size manually. am i right?

Comment: @DmitryYakov You ideally want to use whatever unit of measurement you want to use (pt in this case) as a guide, but use what react-native offers `sp/dp` and try to get as close as possible.